# Get selection value in ALV grid

Tags: selection, abap, alv

I want to get the value of the select cells in ALV, I tried `get_selected_cells` method, but the value field is INITIAL.

What's wrong in this method?

```
FORM delete_livraison .
  DATA: lt_cells  TYPE lvc_t_cell,
        ls_cells  TYPE lvc_s_cell,
        lv_probl  TYPE xfeld.

  gr_alvpl->get_selected_cells(  IMPORTING et_cell = lt_cells ).

  LOOP AT lt_cells INTO ls_cells.
    IF ls_cells-col_id+0(3) NE 'DAY'.
*      lv_probl = 'X'.
    ENDIF.
    IF ls_cells-value IS INITIAL.
      lv_probl  = 'X'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.

  IF lv_probl EQ 'X'.
    MESSAGE s029 DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`get_select_cells` is the wrong method for your task, it returns only **index** user selected **in a row**, not the value selected.

To get selected values use `get_selected_cells( )` and/or `get_selected_rows( )` and together with data internal table:

```
CALL METHOD mo_grid->get_selected_cells
  IMPORTING
    et_cell = lt_cells.

CALL METHOD mo_grid->get_selected_rows
  IMPORTING
    et_row_no = lt_rows.

IF lt_rows IS INITIAL.
  IF lt_cells[] IS INITIAL.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.

  READ TABLE lt_cells INTO ls_cell INDEX 1.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    ls_row-row_id = ls_cell-row_id-index.
    APPEND ls_row TO lt_rows.
  ENDIF.
ENDIF.
    
 LOOP AT lt_rows INTO ls_row.
  READ TABLE <lt_lines> ASSIGNING <ls_line> INDEX ls_row-row_id.
  IF sy-subrc = 0.
    APPEND <ls_line> TO et_lines.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `CL_GUI_CFW=>FLUSH( ).` after `GET_SELECTED_CELLS`, but before evaluating the results. For the technical background, I'd recommend [this document](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/9b/d080ba9fc111d2bd68080009b4534c/content.htm) - a must-read for control programming.

Also be aware that `GET_SELECTED_CELLS` will return the **position** of the selected cells, not the **content**.

Comment: But what Is the value fields

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: In the structure lvc_s_cell you have 3 field, first row, 2nd col_id, 3rd VALUE, why i don't have the value in the last field?